# How to add a selector to a View's border

Tags: android, selector

I have an edittextview with a black colored border. How can I change this border color depending on the state, using a selector.

**I tried this:**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_rounded_borders"
/>
```

**black_rounded_borders.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@drawable/selector_black_border" />


    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**selector_black_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:color="#FF000000"/>

</selector>
```

**EDIT:**

I changed **selector_black_border.xml** to color folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>

</selector>


 <stroke
       android:width="2dp"
       android:color="@color/selector_black_border" />
```

But then it always remain in blue color("#FF269ff5") even when not focused/pressed.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to put the selector inside `color/` and

```
<stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/nameofcolor">
```

Comment: Hey at first I thought It worked, but it didn't. Can you please check the edit part.

Comment: check if the EditText keeps the focus. I will go through step. Start with the pressed on/off and if it works add more states

Comment: No. `editText.hasFocus()` returns `False` at the start of the Activity, but the border is blue.

Comment: try adding states one at time, in order to understand which one is causing the issue

Comment: Only if I remove all the `True` states, it shows black. If I add anyone of the `True` states, It shows blue.

Comment: remove all the "false" attribute and try with the default one. The fact is that one of the statment is meet the match does not continue. So probably one from pressed/focused or selected is still true

Comment: All of `hasFocus(), isPressed(), isSelected()` are false. But like you guessed, its always taking the 1st in the list irrespective of the state :=(

Comment: replace the false with the default, and try again. Add  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to the EditText's parent

Comment: Nope. Nothing changed.